# For odd primes $p$, $n^{2p-1}\equiv n\pmod{2p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove or disprove: If $p$ is an odd prime, then $n^{2p-1}\equiv n\pmod{2p}$.

I feel like there would be two cases, for when $n$ is odd and when $n$ is even but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you seen the Euler Phi function?

Comment: Ah, yes. If m is a positive integer and $(a,m)=1$, $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1(mod m)$. I'm not sure how to use it here though.

Comment: $\phi(2p) = p-1$. Can you use this to solve the case where $(n,2p) = 1$?

Comment: Why is $\phi(2p)=p-1$?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $p\mid n$, then $n^{2p-1} \equiv n\mod(p)$ holds trivially. If $p\nmid n$, then by Fermat's Little theorem
$$
n^{p-1} \equiv 1\mod(p)
$$
Hence,
$$
n^{2p-1} = nn^{p-1}n^{p-1} \equiv n\mod(p)
$$
In either case,
$$
n^{2p-1} \equiv n\mod(p)
$$
Since $2p-1 > 0$,
$$
n^{2p-1} \equiv n\mod(2)
$$
(Again, you can look at $n$ odd and $n$ even separately).

Hence,
$$
p \mid (n^{2p-1} - n), \text{ and } 2\mid (n^{2p-1} -n)
$$
Since $(2,p) = 1$, it follows that
$$
2p \mid (n^{2p-1} - n)
$$
which is what you want.